# Validate row count

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odbc, oracle-xe

I'm making an app where people need to log in, these data are on a Oracle 10g XE DB, I know how to access the data, but I don't know how to validate is the query returns something or doesn't (to validate the username and password, of course). I'm using an ODBC with VB.net to connect the DB. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SELECT COUNT(*)` which will always return some value:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS user_ok FROM my_app_users
WHERE user_id='xxx' 
AND user_passwd=SHA256(user_salt || 'xyz')
```

In case user do not exists or 'xyz' is not a password you will get '0'.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, luckily for me I was able to figure it some days ago.